Trying to make submenu with scrolling in html
I am trying to make a submenu with scrollbars and dropdown list, the ul inside 'some other services' li is appearing inside the parent block. I've tried using position:absolute which pops ul out but the list positions with respect to screen. I want it to be with respective to its parent li position.


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    
    .menu {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .menu-item {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      border-bottom: none;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 14px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .menu-item a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000000;
      display: block;
      transition: .3s background-color;
      padding: 0 24px;
    }
    
    .menu-item a:hover {
      background-color: #5c89c7;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    a {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 0;
      max-height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    .menu-item:hover>.dropdown {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu-item {
      display: block;
      line-height: 34px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu-item:hover>.dropdown {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown" style="margin-left:30%; margin-top:-15%; /* position:absolute; */>
                    <li class=" dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">some other services</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">services</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">services</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">services</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">services</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item "><a href="# ">services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>




You can't break out a positioned element from it's parent's overflow container.

If your menu is that large that you need scrolling, consider perhaps a mega-menu instead

Added position: relative to the .menu-item class
Set position: absolute; for the .dropdown class, along with top: 100%; and left: 0
These changes cause the submenu to appear relative to its parent and maintain its position correctly.

@zara, it did not work, infact it stopped showing menu upon hover.

@Paulie_D, cannot use a mega menu and I've almost achieved the desired result just need to get the positioning right.

AS I said You can't break out a positioned element from it's parent's overflow container.

@Paulie_D, followed your advice and made mega menu, thanks for the advice.

Set the Menu Item position relative and adjust the dropdown CSS as overflow-y: auto;, position: absolute;, top: 100%;, left: 0;, and z-index: 1000;


body {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    
    .menu {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .menu-item {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      border-bottom: none;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 14px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      background-color: white;
      position: relative; 
    }
    
    .menu-item a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000000;
      display: block;
      transition: .3s background-color;
      padding: 0 24px;
    }
    
    .menu-item a:hover {
      background-color: #5c89c7;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    a {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 0;
      max-height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      overflow-y: auto; 
      position: absolute; 
      top: 100%; 
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000; 
}
    
    .menu-item:hover > .dropdown {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu-item {
      display: block;
      line-height: 34px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu-item:hover > .dropdown {
      display: block;
    }
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">some other services</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>



